# How does the Yajurveda and Atharvaveda describe Lord Viṣṇu?

Tags: vedas, vishnu

The verses of Ṛgveda that describe the deed of Lord Viṣṇu taking three strides is quite famous , and also in the Brāhmana Texts Lord Viṣṇu is called Yajñapati and the Yajña itself (correct me if I'm wrong , I don't know if these things are present in Samhitas too) . I wanted to know how the Yajurveda and Atharvaveda Samhitas describe and praise Lord Viṣṇu , and what are the Epithets that he gets in these Samhitas? Thanks[image]